# All Browsers Crashing on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, chromium, gmail

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04, all browsers crash, especially when using Google Mail or Google Drive / Docs. I am using Google Chrome Version 23.0.1271.97 and Chromium Version 23.0.1271.64 Ubuntu 12.04 (165188). Firefox quits on crashing whereas the Chromium based browsers individual tabs crash. The problem also exists with Opera. I have tried creating a new profile. When running Chrome from the command line I get this error on tab crash:

`third_party/tcmalloc/chromium/src/free_list.cc:133] Memory corruption detected.`

as well as `[22322:22322:0102/125148:ERROR:layout.cc(160)] Not implemented reached in ui::ScaleFactor ui::GetScaleFactorForNativeView(GtkWidget*)`

and also `ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream`

I have also tried clearing the cache, uninstalling, purging, reinstalling and still this problem persists. I have tried different versions of Google Chrome and still this problem persists.

What should I try next / what output should I include to help in finding the problem?

Comment: Maybe your problem isn't software related, but hardware. You could run the memtest on Ubuntu install media, LiveCD or USB install, to check for problems in your memory modules.

Comment: What's your DE? If Unity, go to Unity 2D, it can fix some problems.

Comment: @ThiagoPonte - you got it in one! Ran memtest and thousands or errors appeared immediately. Just bought some new RAM and all is now good! Thank you :)

Comment: Glad i could help. I guess my answer shouldn't have been converted to comment after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your problem isn't software related, but hardware.

You could run the memtest on Ubuntu install media, LiveCD or USB install, to check for problems in your memory modules.

Glad i could help you [Mark Aroni](https://askubuntu.com/users/118148/mark-aroni).